# Set check of CMFCRibbonCheckBox

Tags: mfc, mfc-feature-pack

The MFC `CMFCRibbonCheckBox` class only supports `IsChecked()`.
How do I change check status of ribbon check box in program code?
Is there way to set check status like `CButton::SetCheck()`.

Answer (score 1):

you can copy code from CMFCRibbonCmdUI::SetCheck. CMFCRibbonBaseElement::m_bIsPressed is a protected member so you need to expose it via a derived class. CMFCRibbonCmdUI has a backdoor to it through class friendship.

Comment: It seems that there is no chance to add derived class into ribbon control that is created by an Ribbon resource editor.

Comment: CMFCRibbonConstructor::CreateElement is virtual... but it is a lot of work to use a derived CMFCRibbonConstructor. much easier if you can use CMFCRibbonCmdUI directly.